# How to "eager load" a service in AngularJS? (instantiate it before its needed, automatically)

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization, angularjs-service

I'm trying to achieve a program structure like this:

[image]

The problem here is, when there is no apparent controller using the Features in the beginning, they are not instantiated and not registered in the `FeatureRegistry`, therefore they can't show up in the View. But what I would like is to achieve is that they show up in the view, then there template is loaded via `ng-include` and then in the template there are specific controllers for each feauture. These controllers are the ones that are using the Features.

The features are basically only there to tell about the location of templates and icons, which to use, and also to kick off the start of the Feature.

But back to my initial question:
**How to instantiate the services even if they are not needed at the moment?**

Or is there another function, that I can use for that instead of service? I would also like if you point me to that then :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can ask for it in the `run` part of your application, injector will invoke it.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
    factory("EagerService", function () {
        console.log("I'm ready.");
    }).
    run(function (EagerService) {
        console.log("EagerService is ready.");
    });
```

Yet, as far as I understand, you have child/sub controllers that need this `EagerService`. Why don't you inject it there?

Comment: They have to be included first, by the `FeatureViewController` .. he is supposed to include the templates in the view with the controllers

Comment: If you use a webpack, you need to have at least one code line inside run, because webpack does not enter in funtion if no code there. So, in my case, I use `return;` instead of `console.log`

Answer (score 8):

(Since this is relatively old - this answer is for future readers - but I stumbled across this question so maybe someone else will too) If you use providers/config blocks - they are done eagerly, so it's better to do eager initialization code there.  You are/were probably thinking in terms of services/run blocks.

To demonstrate with code, this alert will not pop (assuming `myServiceModule` is a module that your application depends on and `myService` is not injected anywhere):

```
angular.module('myServiceModule', []).service('myService', function () {
    alert("service");

    // service
    return {};
});
```

However **this alert will pop even if no one is depending on the `myProvider` service**:

```
angular.module('myProviderModule', []).provider('myProvider', function () {
    alert("provider");

    // Define your service here. Can be an array of inject-ables 
    // instead of a function.
    this.$get = function () {
        // service
        return {};
    };
});
```

You can see this in action in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qjcNlMIefDb3kPfhrVqz?p=preview).

Read more about providers in the official documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).